# Laravel: Automatically add parameter to urls

Tags: laravel, routes

I have an application in which you can create a service and a service can have its own partial view.
So I created a route group with {service} prefix:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{service}', ... ], ... ).
// http://.../my-service/my-url
```

However, in order to know in which service the user is I need to add the service in every single route I have in my application. So I have done a middleware that shares $service to every view:

```
view()->share(['service' => $service])
```

But I don't know how to add $service prefix to every route without explicitly adding it. I would like doing something like

```
route()->prefix(['service' => $service])
```

and then every route have the prefix $service:

```
url("myurl") // -> url("$service/my-url") or
route('my-route')
```

Any idea?

**EDIT:**

Finally I decided to create a ServiceType model, create a middleware with a parameter and set to my route groups. Then in view I offer the user to switch between services of the same type.
Not is what I was looking but it's OK for now.
Question is still open if anyone knows the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put all your routes you want prefixed in a group and then add the prefix

[Laravel docs on route prefixes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-group-prefixes)

Comment: How will that help me to add a prefix to every url I want to generate?

Comment: By only defining the prefix once on your group? Maybe I didn't understand your question, but I thought this is what you wanted